# Where does Confluent's kafka-avro-console-consumer write its log files?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am running Confluent's [`kafka-avro-console-consumer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer) as described in the [quickstart tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart.html):

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic test --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning
```

However, I have created a separate user `kafka` to run this command. I get the error message

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/bin/../logs': Permission denied
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/bin/../logs/schema-registry.log (No such file or directory)
[...]
```

I would rather not give the `kafka` write access to the entire `/usr/bin` directory. Where exactly is Kafka trying to create the `logs` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kafka-avro-console-consumer` respects the `LOG_DIR` environment variable so if you set it, the log file will be written to this directory instead.

Comment: Anders can you provide anymore detail?
I set the `LOG_DIR` variable to point to `/var/log` in my .bashrc and even though it prints `/var/log` when echoed, running the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` command still reports the error and points the file permission error to the `/usr/bin` base path.

Comment: I think this is a pure unix/bash issue. You can try to set LOG_DIR directly on the command line just before the kafka-avro-console-consumer command. Set it to something you know for sure you can write to. For example     `LOG_DIR=~ /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer  ...`